# What is the difference between '新型冠状病毒防控是当务之急。' and ' 防控新型冠状病毒是当务之急。'?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Anyone who can explain the difference well?

Comment: No difference in meaning but the first sentence isn't as good as the second one.

Comment: Just the trick of a verb or noun. And usually, the first word is emphasised, so depends on the intention of the sentence is to emphasis the object or the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 新型冠状病毒(adjectival noun) 防控(n)是当务之急(relative clause)

> Novel Coronavirus prevention and control is an urgent priority

~

> 防控(v)新型冠状病毒(n)是当务之急(relative clause)

> To prevent and control Novel Coronavirus is an urgent priority

Comment: Thank you very much.